# SQL subquery syntax checking other records

Tags: sql, join, subquery

I need to find policies in a table that have 0 premium, but not if another policy with the same policy number has premium.  Here is my pseudocode:

```
select * from tblPolicies where premium = 0
(but not if anther record has the same policyNumber and premium <> 0)
```

I know that is terrible, but I'm lost and that was the best I could come up with!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Possible Query 1:**

```
SELECT M.* FROM tblPolicies AS M
WHERE premium = 0 AND policyNumber NOT IN 
(
   SELECT S.policyNumber 
   FROM tblPolicies AS S 
   WHERE S.policyNumber = M.policyNumber
   AND S.premium <> 0 
)
```

**Possible Query 2:**

```
SELECT SA.* FROM 
(
  SELECT M.* FROM tblPolicies AS M
  WHERE premium = 0
) AS SA
INNER JOIN tblPolicies AS SB
ON SA.policyNumber = SB.policyNumber 
WHERE SB.premium <> 0
```

**Possible Query 3:**

```
SELECT * FROM tblPolicies AS SA
INNER JOIN tblPolicies AS SB
ON SA.policyNumber = SB.policyNumber 
WHERE SA.premium = 0 AND SB.premium <> 0
```

Comment: This works and I appreciate it, but it is incredibly slow...  Anyway to increase performance?

Comment: Do you have an index on policyNumber?  Also, how many records are in the table?  What DBMS is it (SQL Server, MySQL, MS Access, etc..)?

Comment: ***@daytonk***, I added a couple more queries to my answer that may work better for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
select p_no from 
(select p_no, sum(premium) as tot_prem from policy group by p_no) as pol 
where tot_prem>0;
```

p_no->**premium_no**

policy->**policy table**